# what is special about opponents who have a full highlighted floor indicator?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

When getting into big fights with several triad thugs, they all have different indicator statuses underneath them.

There are indicators for Brawlers, ones for Grapplers, hollow indicators for 'generic bad guy' and then another type - a solid red/orange highlighted one.

I don't recall this type of indicator being referred to in game, so what is special about these type of triad thugs?

All I can work out is that it appears you can't grapple with them initially, but that's the case with other opponents to. Is there a reason some triads have this highlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are just tougher and require more effort to make 'em weak enough so that you can finally grapple them.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special. You just gotta wear them down even more to grapple 'em.

Answer (score 0):

The highlighted floor indicator signifies the triad member's health level i.e. it's just a health bar.